# Search listbox for string, DataSource property set

Tags: vb.net, listbox, datasource

I'm trying to make `TextBox1` a search bar, to search for specific strings in `ListBox1`.

I want it to remove other items that don't have the string I searched. The list shows all files in a specific directory, so if I search **"icon_"** it would **only** show files with **icon_** in the name. Is this possible?

I've asked this question a while ago, but I can't use any of the answers because the listbox is being populated by filenames from a specific directory, which gives me this error:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different ways to do this.

This method puts your list of files into a DataTable and using a BindingSource, you can use it's Filter property to filter the list.

Here is a form with a ListBox and a TextBox:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim bs As New BindingSource

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    Dim testPath As String = "c:\MyPath"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("File", GetType(String))

    For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(testPath)
      Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow
      row("File") = Path.GetFileName(f)
      dt.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    bs.DataSource = dt

    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "File"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "File"
    ListBox1.DataSource = bs
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    bs.Filter = String.Format("File LIKE '*{0}*'", TextBox1.Text)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `DataSource` property is set, you cannot modify the list.  While it is convenient to populate a `ListBox` control using the `DataSource` property, it is certainly not necessary.  You can add the items to the control using its `Items.Add` method, instead.  For instance, borrowing from my answer to your previous question:

```
Public Class FileSearchTool
    Public Sub New(ByVal listBox As ListBox, ByVal textBox As TextBox)
        _listBox = listBox
        _textBox = textBox
    End Sub

    Private _listBox As ListBox
    Private WithEvents _textBox As TextBox
    Private _fileNames As New List(Of String)()
    Private _folderPath As String

    Public Property FolderPath() As String
        Get
            Return _folderPath
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _folderPath = value
            loadFilePaths()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub loadFilePaths()
        _fileNames = New List(Of String)(Directory.GetFiles(_folderPath))
        refreshList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _textBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles _textBox.TextChanged
        refreshList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub refreshList()
        _listBox.SuspendLayout()
        _listBox.Items.Clear()
        For Each item As String In _fileNames
            If item.StartsWith(_textBox.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                _listBox.Items.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
        _listBox.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in any form you could use it like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _tool As FileSearchTool
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _tool = New FileSearchTool(ListBox1, TextBox1)
        _tool.FolderPath = "C:\"
    End Sub
End Class
```

But, at that point, you might as well just encapsulate it further by creating a FileSearch user control.

Or, As I said in my answer to your previous question, if all you want is an auto complete box, you can just use a text box without a listbox at all as such:

```
Dim source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
source.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\"))
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
```

In fact, another interesting option is that you can set `AutoCompleteSource` to `FileSystem`, which you may want to play with.